# List all VLookups in a Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have a big Excel file with lots of different sheets, each containing lots of vlookups.

I want to move this file and some files linked to it to a new folder.

I changed the paths in the macros, but is there a way to spot all the vlookups among all the worksheets which have an external link ? I mean by that a link to one of those files I will also move (therefore I should change their path).

If there is a way to list all the Vlookups present in the file with the cell they are in + the cell they are looking at, it would be great.

Comment: Check out this link: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1001%20range.find%20and%20findall.shtml

Comment: Thanks...It actually made me realize that I could simply use Find&Replace and sort that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will collect cells with formulas and return a Range object.

```
function FindFormulaInSheet(ws As Worksheet, functionName As String) as Range
    Dim formulas As Range     
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        If InStr(c.Formula, "VLOOKUP") > 0 Then
            If formulas Is Nothing Then
                Set formulas = c
            Else
                Set formulas = Union(formulas, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
    set FindFormulaInSheet = formulas
End function
```

So, in your case call it for example (will mark all VLOOKUP with yellow):

```
dim r as Range
set r = FindFormulaInSheet (activeSheet, "VLOOKUP")
r.interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Instead of marking it yellow, of course you can do anything with you want the range.

Comment: yes, I can actually do `r.Formula =" MYNEWPATH"` ...thanks Thomas